# Why my JLabels print out in same exact space?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel, layout-manager

I am trying to make a program that is used on my warehouse using JFrames for different screens. Login screen shows perfectly like i coded, fail screen won't show at all and the successful login main menu screen takes all 3 JLabels which i put for different lines and print them all in exact same spot so you can't see what it says.

At the beginning i thought it has something with parts of code being in wrong place but after copying it elsewhere nothing changed. For the first screen i needed to create empty JLabel at the end of frame code which sorted exactly same problem but it won't work same with main menu screen

```
public class Login {
    public Login() {
        JFrame login = new JFrame("RedPraire");
        JFrame mmenu = new JFrame("RedPraire");
        JFrame failed = new JFrame("RedPraire");

        JLabel acc = new JLabel("Username:"); 
        JLabel pass = new JLabel("Password:");
        JLabel page = new JLabel("1/1");
        JLabel mm1 = new JLabel("1 System Directed");
        JLabel mm2 = new JLabel("2 User Directed");
        JLabel mm3 = new JLabel("3 Logout");
        JLabel site = new JLabel("Thorne");
        JLabel info = new JLabel("RPPRODWMS (PL0236)");
        JLabel title = new JLabel("Login");
        JLabel titlemm = new JLabel("MainMenu");
        JLabel sitemm = new JLabel("W114");
        JLabel selmm = new JLabel("Selection?");
        JLabel createdby = new JLabel("(c) JDA 1995-2018");
        JLabel flogin = new JLabel("Invalid username or password press enter...");
        JLabel x = new JLabel("");
        JTextField acc1 = new JTextField("") ;
        JTextField pass1 = new JTextField("");


        login.setSize(600, 380);
        login.setVisible(true);
        login.setResizable(false);
        login.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        login.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        login.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.black);

        failed.setSize(600, 380);
        failed.setVisible(false);
        failed.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        failed.setResizable(false);
        failed.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        failed.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.black);

        mmenu.setSize(600, 380);
        mmenu.setVisible(false);
        mmenu.setResizable(false);
        mmenu.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mmenu.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        mmenu.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.black);

        title.setBounds(270, 2, 40, 20);
        title.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 14));
        title.setForeground(Color.white);

        page.setBounds(2, 2, 40, 20);
        page.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 14));
        page.setForeground(Color.white);

        info.setBounds(2, 30, 160, 20);
        info.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 14));
        info.setForeground(Color.white);

        site.setBounds(2, 50, 120, 20);
        site.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 14));
        site.setForeground(Color.white);

        acc.setBounds(2, 70, 160, 20);
        acc.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 14));
        acc.setForeground(Color.white);

        pass.setBounds(2, 90, 160, 20);
        pass.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 14));
        pass.setForeground(Color.white);

        createdby.setBounds(2, 220, 160, 20);
        createdby.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 14));
        createdby.setForeground(Color.white);

        login.add(title);
        login.add(page);
        login.add(site);
        login.add(info);
        login.add(acc);
        login.add(pass);
        login.add(createdby);
        login.add(acc1);
        login.add(pass1);
        login.add(x);

        acc1.setBounds(82, 70, 160, 20);
        acc1.setBackground(Color.black);
        acc1.setForeground(Color.white);
        acc1.setCaretColor(Color.white);
        acc1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 1, 0, Color.white));
        acc1.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                    if(acc1.getText().equals("jud") && (pass1.getText().equals("sze"))) {
                        login.setVisible(false);
                        mmenu.setVisible(true);


                        selmm.setBounds(2, 220, 160, 20);
                        selmm.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 14));
                        selmm.setForeground(Color.white);

                        mm1.setBounds(2, 70, 160, 20);
                        mm1.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 14));
                        mm1.setForeground(Color.white);

                        mm2.setBounds(2, 90, 160, 20);
                        mm2.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 14));
                        mm2.setForeground(Color.white);

                        mm3.setBounds(2, 110, 160, 20);
                        mm3.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 14));
                        mm3.setForeground(Color.white);

                        titlemm.setBounds(270, 2, 40, 20);
                        titlemm.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 14));
                        titlemm.setForeground(Color.white);

                        sitemm.setBounds(2, 50, 120, 20);
                        sitemm.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 14));
                        sitemm.setForeground(Color.white);

                        flogin.setBounds(30, 200, 200, 20);
                        flogin.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 14));
                        flogin.setForeground(Color.white);

                        mmenu.add(page);
                        mmenu.add(createdby);
                        mmenu.add(titlemm);
                        mmenu.add(sitemm);
                        mmenu.add(selmm);
                        mmenu.add(mm1);
                        mmenu.add(mm2);
                        mmenu.add(mm3);
                        mmenu.add(x);

                    } else {
                        login.setVisible(false);
                        flogin.setVisible(true);

                        failed.add(flogin);
                        failed.add(page);
                        failed.add(x);

                    }
                }
            }
        });

        pass1.setBounds(82, 90, 160, 20);
        pass1.setCaretColor(Color.white);
        pass1.setBackground(Color.black);
        pass1.setForeground(Color.white);
        pass1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 1, 0, Color.white));;
        pass1.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                    if(acc1.getText().equals("jud") && (pass1.getText().equals("sze"))) {
                        login.setVisible(false);
                        mmenu.setVisible(true);


                        selmm.setBounds(2, 220, 160, 20);
                        selmm.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 14));
                        selmm.setForeground(Color.white);

                        mm1.setBounds(2, 70, 160, 20);
                        mm1.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 14));
                        mm1.setForeground(Color.white);

                        mm2.setBounds(2, 70, 160, 20);
                        mm2.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 14));
                        mm2.setForeground(Color.white);

                        mm3.setBounds(2, 70, 160, 20);
                        mm3.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 14));
                        mm3.setForeground(Color.white);

                        titlemm.setBounds(270, 2, 40, 20);
                        titlemm.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 14));
                        titlemm.setForeground(Color.white);

                        sitemm.setBounds(2, 50, 120, 20);
                        sitemm.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 14));
                        sitemm.setForeground(Color.white);

                        flogin.setBounds(30, 200, 200, 20);
                        flogin.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 14));
                        flogin.setForeground(Color.white);

                        mmenu.add(page);
                        mmenu.add(createdby);
                        mmenu.add(titlemm);
                        mmenu.add(sitemm);
                        mmenu.add(selmm);
                        mmenu.add(mm1);
                        mmenu.add(mm2);
                        mmenu.add(mm3);
                        mmenu.add(x);


                    } else {
                        login.setVisible(false);
                        flogin.setVisible(true);

                        failed.add(flogin);
                        failed.add(page);
                        failed.add(x);

                    }
                }
            }
        });






    }

}
```

they're supposed to be different lines as you could see in my code but it is all blurred in altogether in one line..

Comment: Which [layout manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) are you using? Please create a [mcve]. The code you provided is insufficient to understand your problem.

Comment: `setBounds` is not a good way to do layout. You should definitly learn about `LayoutManager`s and how to use them properly. They are really powerful with what you can do with them

Comment: okay if it is not any advice on exact one i should use in this case? i am just the beginner so it would be nice with any advice on what to look for exactly. Thanks

Comment: I can only suppose they are nowhere, missing code adding them to a component and the settings of that component - please edit the question and add a [mcve] (already asked for almost 30 minutes ago by RealSkeptic)

Comment: the first word was **minimal**   [:-(

Comment: just edited and this time i have shown whole code

Comment: read my previous comment... also `login` is a `JFrame` that uses a `BorderLayout` by default and, since no constraint is given, `CENTER` is used when adding elements. Therefore all elements are being added to the *same* region, the last always removing the previous... check official tutorial: [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Comment: *"on exact one"* The trick is to *combine* layouts as needed. Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used. BTW - See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) A login would typically be done in a (modal) dialog or a `JOptionPane`.

Comment: Other tips: 1) `JTextField pass1 = new JTextField("");` should be a `JPasswordField`. 2) `mm1` and it's other options might instead be `JRadioButton`s or `JButton`s or choices in a `JComboBox` or .. 3) `new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 14)` Use generic fonts (`Font.SANS_SERIF`) or specifically test for it. Create the font once and use it as needed. 4) `.setForeground(Color.white);` This screams for a factory method or changing the `UIDefaults` 5) `login.setVisible(true);` This should be done after all components are added. 6) `login.setSize(600, 380);` That's a guess. Instead call `pack()`.

Comment: The thing about JPasswordField is that as i am still new to this after it saved my password in some weird code i couldn't find a way how to log in as it was saying password is incorrect so i just skipped password for now :(and from what i see you've wrote Andrew Thompson and how much i think i should skip all JFrames for now until i'll understand all much better :/ it's just that except of simple hello world and things you can't really find good learning website which is free.

Comment: *"The thing about.."* ..replies is that no one will be notified unless you **tag them.** Tip: Add @CarlosHeuberger (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Just so everyone who tried to help me after digging for few days all forums the solution is very easy without telling that this is too powerful to use it works perfectly how? Simple. I have created every frame as different class then when it checks for the password if is correct if true i used this:

```
login.setVisible(false);
login.dispose();
new MainMenu();
```

where creates new frame with attributes needed and they are not mixed together like they were before. Next time before telling someone to not use something (as they would like to say you are not good enough) just come up with solution like  Andrew Thompson tried to :)
Thanks